# Port forward to iOS (adb reverse equivalent)

Tags: ios, macos, create-react-app

I am trying to test my create-react-app on my tablet and phone (iOS 9). I am on Mac OS X 10.12.6 - I am not able to load localhost:3000 on my tablet. Is this possible? Port forwarding was what i was researching but I couldnt figure it out.

On Android on windows I am able to do `adb reverse tcp:3000 tcp:3000` but I cannot find the equivalent on iOS devices and Mac OS X.

Comment: You don't want port forwarding (it isn't available on iOS in any case); you need to find the IP address of your mac and use that instead of `localhost`.  Network preferences will show you your Mac's IP address

Comment: Thanks very much that did the trick @Paulw11 !! :)

Comment: Hi ystal Can you share how did you implemented it?

Comment: @AbilashBansal You can find your Mac port by typing in the terminal `ifconfig` which will list a wall of text, you have to find the line that starts with `inet 192.***.*.**` typically under `en0:` entry and that's your port